# Pass a file name using EJS after a ASYNC function was finished expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Basically what I want to do is as a button is clicked generate a order page and then generate a PNG and then pass the location of the generated PNG through with ejs to show that page and the rendered image.

I get this error:
node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const path = require('path');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))


// index page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');

});

app.get('/cashpayment/:paymentId', async function(req,res){
  const paymentId = req.params.paymentId;
  const orders = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('orders.json'));
  const foundOrder = orders.find(order => String(order.paymentId) === paymentId);
  if (foundOrder) {
    async function m1(){
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 })
      await page.goto('https://www.nytimes.com/')
      await page.screenshot({ path: './public/nytimes.png', fullPage: true })
      await browser.close()
      await console.log('done');
      res.render('app', {
        data:'./public/nytimes.png'
      })
    }
    let finished = await m1();
    console.log(finished);
  }

  res.sendStatus(404);
});

app.post('/cashpayment', async function(req,res){
  const paymentId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);
  const orders = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('orders.json'));
  orders.push({paymentId, paymentAmount: 10, paymentStatus: "UNPAID", token: ""});
  fs.writeFileSync('orders.json', JSON.stringify(orders));
  res.redirect(`/cashpayment/${paymentId}`);
});

// about page
app.listen(1337);
console.log('Server is listening on port 8080');
```

Comment: your handler executes `res.sendStatus(404)` in any case, even if `foundOrder` evaluates to a truthy and your `m1` function already sent a result via `res.render()` that is not allowed ...

Comment: BTW using `readFileSync` and `writeFileSync` in an `async` function is quite a bad idea, because it blocks the whole process. Use `readFile/writeFile` from [`fs/promises`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) instead ...  Furthermore, without specifiyng an encoding, `fs.readFileSync` will return a `Buffer` I'm wondering how `JSON.parse` doesn't throw an error ...